# Simple string replace against character

Tags: php, string

I have a string such as :

```
"Hello ? My name is ? I am ? years old"
```

And I have an array such as :

```
['George','Jonathan',35]
```

I'd like a result of combining and returning:

```
`Hello "Geroge" My name is "Jonathan" I am "35" years old`
```

How do i accomplish this in php?

I tried using `str_ireplace` but it said "array to string conversion"

Comment: "I tried using..." - "but it said"... so, details matter.  str_ireplace would work, actually - but _how_ you "tried using" it makes the difference.  Please consider adding an [mcve]

Comment: check all solutions and accept the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`vsprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) because you want to replace it with an array:

```
<?php
$array = ['George','Jonathan',35];
$content = vsprintf("Hello %s My name is %s I am %s years old", $array);
echo $content; // Hello George My name is Jonathan I am 35 years old
```

**From PHP Manual:** `vsprintf()` Operates as [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) but accepts an array of arguments, rather than a variable number of arguments.

Above is a solution, but how can you change the `?` from your string, here you can use `str_replace()` to replace with `%s`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to change the way you define placeholders in your string, you should use `sprintf`. [Check out the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php).

Simple example:

```
$result = sprintf("Hello %s My name is %s I am %d years old", 'George', 'Jonathan', 35);
```

In your case, you could use the splat operator (php >= 5.6) in order to pass the variables:

```
$variables = ['George', 'Jonathan', 35];
$result = sprintf("Hello %s My name is %s I am %d years old", ...$variables);
```

As others pointed out, the `vsprintf` function may be a better way. [See devpro's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381487/3808452)

Comment: Except "I have an array".... you've got explicit strings getting swapped in.  How to do it with an _array of values_?

Comment: `vsprintf` exists too.

Comment: How does this involve a string with `?` as placeholders?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try with something like this. You can still use `?` as a questionmark then. Also the types and amount are not fixed.

```
<?php
function insert($values, $string) {
    $string = str_replace(
        [' ? ', '? ', ' ?'],
        [' %s ', '%s ', ' %s'],
        $string
    );
    return vsprintf($string, $values);
}



$string = "Hello ?. My name is ? I am ? years old. How are you?";
$values = ['you', 'Dan', '+- 30'];

// Prints: Hello you. My name is Dan I am +- 30 years old. How are you?
echo insert($values, $string), PHP_EOL;

// Prints: Nice nice!
echo insert(['nice'], 'Nice ?!'), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: good one , like this .. vote for u, actually u mentioned correct point, about `?` so i just update in my answer also.. thank u

Answer (score 1):

To set an array of variables, you can use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```php
<?php
call_user_func_array('sprintf', ['Hello %s My name is %s I am %d years old', 'George', 'Jonathan', 35]);
```